# Alert if a user is added to Global Admin in Azure AD

Tags: entra-id

We are looking to set up a solution to monitor primarily the *Global Admin* role in Azure AD, so if a user is added to or removed from the role an e-mail is sent to a specific mailbox.

On our local AD we have a working solution for this, but I can't seem to find a similar solution for AAD.

In the *Office 365 Security & Compliance Center > Alerts > Alert Policies* there is a policy called "Elevation of Exchange admin privilege" which basically does what I want, except it only targets the Exchange Admin role.

I've tried creating a new policy from scratch, but as far as I can tell there is no way to choose to target a specific role. There is only the "Granted Exchange admin permission" and nothing really comes up when I search for "role" or "admin" in the "Activity is" drop down.

I've also looked at the MCAS (MS Cloud App Security) policies but nothing there seems to be what I need either.

I've already configured notifications through PIM in *Azure AD > Privileged Identity Management > [TENANT NAME] | Roles > Global Administrator | Role Settings* so we get an alert whenever someone is either "assigned as eligible to this role:" or "assigned as active to this role:".

But if someone adds a user directly to the *Global Administrator* role via *Azure AD > [TENANT NAME] | Roles and administrators* no mail is sent, even though the user is visible as an active Global Administrator in PIM.

I found this article: [Monitor Office 365 admin role changes in all customer tenants](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/monitor-office-365-admin-role-changes-in-all-customer-tenants/) but it seems to be geared more towards multitenant environments and requires quite a bit och additional setup. I was hoping there was a simpler solution for a single tenant environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use Azure AD Privileged Identity Management (PIM), if a user was assigned outside PIM, you'll get notified by email.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-how-to-configure-security-alerts?tabs=new#roles-are-being-assigned-outside-of-privileged-identity-management

Comment: Thank you. I have found the alert, but as far as I can tell there's no way to configure it to send the alert to a specific address. We have an alerts distribution group which should receive these alerts, so without the possibility for adding a custom address it does not do everything we need. Should probably have added that to the question, but it seemed natural to have te ability to configure recipients for such an alert. Mea Culpa.

Comment: Don't think that's possible at the time being, I haven't tested this yet but it might be possible that the email is sent to PIM admins/readers: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-how-to-give-access-to-pim

Comment: I believe that it is, which might be OK in some cases, but we are managing a tenant for a client so our admin-user accounts are not licensed for a mailbox in that tenant and therefore any alerts sent to those are for all intents and purposes going to /dev/null. It does not seem like a unique case, but here we are.